# My answer adds nothing, and contains false information. However editing it to correct it would copy another

Tags: discussion, answers

[Explanation of a pointer in exploit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295954/explanation-of-a-pointer-in-exploit-code/)

I answered that after some haphazard googling of the thing. It turns out, after @Mormegil 's Answer, that I completly and utterly misunderstood the problem. I could correct my answer now, but that would just be blatantly using Mormegil's answer as a resource, and even with attribution that feels dirty, as my answer is highly upvoted (+17 | -4). Deleting my answer would be an alternative, but it would cost me 162 reputation points.

What to do, meta?

I deleted it :/

Comment: Note that if you delete your own answer, you will lose the rep, but you will get a nice new badge.

Comment: Don't worry, you just converted your meaningless internet rep points into meaningful real life rep points.

Comment: @TinyGiant the information in that post was not useful though. It is not just not helpful to most, but actively false. Other people probably thought it was right and upvoted because of that, and Im afraid letting highly upvoted demonstrably false info up is going to do damage to future readers.

Comment: Make sure you've upvoted the other answer that you think is correct.

Comment: You should've replaced it with lorem ipsum and check how long it takes before people vote it back to zero. But of course, moderator would delete it first.

Comment: Upvote other answer, delete yours.

Comment: My solution would have been to _edit_ the answer, leaving the old answer there, commenting on it, and correcting it.

Comment: Undelete it and edit it to reflect that is was wrong. If people upvoted you and it is in fact wrong, then there is a lot of other people who also falsely believe the same

Comment: Thanks for your honesty. It's always great when we listen to our conscience.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Funny that a sloppy and inapplicable answer would get so highly upvoted. If you're confident that it is worthless, the best thing *for the site* would be to delete your answer and wave goodbye to the undeserved reputation, wouldn't it.

If you can't bring yourself to give up the internet points, you could always add a big banner at the top saying "This answer is incorrect, I'm leaving it up because <insert excuse about how it may be useful to some people>".

If there's already a correct answer to the same question, you don't help anyone by copying its contents... and you should avoid it for all the reasons you mentioned. One correct answer is enough.

To elaborate, your choices (besides copying the right answer) are to delete your answer, delete all content and replace it with a message, or add a message on top without deleting the current content. Somehow I wouldn't advise leaving up just the message-- the incorrect information is what people voted up (and down).

Comment: Its worthless in almost its entirety. My new level of information on the subject is only exactly what the other answer added to it. I can't just fix that into the Answer, that would be dirty.

Comment: leave a comment as a start ....

Comment: @rene a comment saying what? "I found out now that this answer is utterly worthless and please ignore or downvote it?"

Comment: @Magisch, Read my answer again (the complete suggestion for the comment was hidden due to a formatting error).

Comment: Yes, exactly that (leave out the *downvote it* part) @Magisch

Comment: @rene that would be blatantly incorrect. The two articles I linked turned out to be unrelated, and everything in that answer is better and more understandably answered by the other one.

Comment: It would be blatantly incorrect to say "My answer is incorrect"? I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: @alexis the insert excuse about how it may be useful to some people.

Comment: Gotcha. I see you deleted the content, that's fine too. Interesting that your incorrect answer got 18 upvotes (and seven downvotes, but that's only -2 per downvote: +164 points in all), while the right answer only got 12 upvotes so far.

Comment: @alexis I deleted it. Goodbye fake internet points. I wont leave an Answer up that I know is incorrect.

Comment: Kudos. It must feel nice, doing the right thing. There will be more points :-)

Comment: @alexis will take a few more days to get to 2k then, meh. That should have gotten downvoted anyways, so not really loosing anything.

Comment: @Magisch If it makes you feel better, your answer isn't altogether incorrect (although, indeed, Mormegil's answer is better).  The code *is* setting the UID and GID to zero.  The only _mistake_ in your answer is that NULL pointers are not involved.

Comment: You could just make a post saying you deleted it so you get upvoted for doing the right thing so you don't lose the internet points you would have retained... oh. :P

Answer (score 20):

Deleting it is the quick and easy path, and often the right one.

You are now in the position of owning the top slot on the question.  This is a responsibility.

The hard path would be to learn from the other answer.  Craft a magnificent answer based on what you learned, and learn from elsewhere.  Include graphics, freehand red circles, and bullet points if they help (you know, flare).

Make your answer worthy of the currently unearned votes and reputation.

While ideally you'd learn more than the other answer, if not possible you can attempt to *present* the information way better than the other answer does.

This isn't always possible.  Sometimes you don't have the ability or time to learn more than the other answer.  Sometimes they already presented it better than your abilities to do so contain.

Comment: The other answer was clear, concise, on point and walked through the thing entirely. Its what I would have answered (maybe even better) if I knew wtf I was doing at the time I answered. I don't have the time to go neck deeper into kernel exploits then the other answer, and copying it and trying to format it felt dirty. So I deleted it. The alternative would have been leaving it up and forgetting about it, causing future readers to see highly upvoted but utterly false information. :(

Answer (score 17):

To echo Yakk's answer it can be valuable to describe why it *appears* as if your answer is correct, and then go on to explain why the other question is correct instead. Since it is obvious that at least 17 people (plus you) were initially fooled by your answer this would be a great learning moment.

This would also allow others to chime in explaining why your answer is correct after all. That will allow you to teach the doubters why they're wrong and/or learn why your answer might be a better solution than you believe right now...

Answer (score 9):

If the answer is upvoted despite containing the wrong info then don't delete it -- it indicates that at a glance the wrong approach seems reasonable and it may confuse many people; instead **add a disclaimer at the very top** that clearly says that your answer is incorrect and provide a direct link to the answer that you consider correct.

You could also add an optional explanation why you think your old answer is wrong.

Comment: I'd say it would be more useful to delete the wrong answer, and edit the right answer to add a note at the bottom saying, basically, "You might be tempted to do this, but it's wrong, here's why."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: non-trivial edits of other answers are usually frown upon.

Comment: Ones that improve the answer aren't, in my experience, but yes I would keep it as short as feasible. His original erroneous answer is less than half the length of the correct one, and could be shortened further in its new context.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: how do you know that it improves the answer? There is a reason why multiple answers are allowed to the same question.

Comment: I'm following your assumption that the content has value in a kind of cautionary tale sense. Multiple *correct* answers are fine; leaving an incorrect answer standalone is not, in my view.

Comment: Yes, in the ideal world the cautionary tale is a part of a correct answer but we don't live in the ideal world: OP may think that the answer is wrong but OP may be mistaken about the specific reasons, or OP has no time/desire for more than a quick disclaimer at the top. For the same reason not all downvoted answers should be deleted -- if there is a **clear** indication that the answer is wrong; it may be useful to keep it around e.g., to prevent new wrong answers.